# How to get avatar url of the person who sent the message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How do you get the avatar url of the person who sent the command from the context?

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print("Username is = " + ctx.message.author)
    print(ctx.message.author + "'s avatar url is = " )
```

As you can see, I can easily get the author from the context, but how do I get their avatar picture?

I've seen solutions for this, but its not from the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the author's avatar url just use `ctx.message.author.avatar_url`

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print("Username is = " + ctx.message.author)
    print(ctx.message.author + "'s avatar url is = " + ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
```